# Issues in flask-restless due to sqlalchemy.db.Boolean

Tags: sqlalchemy, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-restless

I have just moved from flask-sqlalchemy to just sqlalchemy. And I have started getting below issue.

**Issue 1** :
I have two models

```
class Candidate(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'candidate'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('country.id'), nullable=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False, server_default=db.text("false"))


class Country(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'country'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False, unique=True)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=_get_date_time)
    modified_on = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, onupdate=_get_date_time, nullable=False, server_default=db.text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False, server_default=db.text("false"))
```

I created tables in my `students` db using alembic. The migration file it generated looks like

```
# ... snip ...
op.create_table('country',
sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=150), nullable=False),
sa.Column('created_on', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
sa.Column('modified_on', sa.TIMESTAMP(), server_default=sa.text(u'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'), nullable=False),
sa.Column('is_deleted', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text(u'false'), nullable=False),
sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
sa.UniqueConstraint('name')
)

op.create_table('candidate',
sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
sa.Column('first_name', sa.String(length=100), nullable=True),
sa.Column('last_name', sa.String(length=100), nullable=True),
sa.Column('country_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
sa.Column('email', sa.String(length=255), nullable=False),
sa.Column('is_deleted', sa.Boolean(), server_default=sa.text(u'false'), nullable=False),
sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['country_id'], ['country.id'], ),
sa.UniqueConstraint('email'),
)
```

I loaded data from the `mysqldump` that I had created when I was using `falsk-sqlalchemy`.

```
INSERT INTO `country` VALUES (1,'India','2015-05-16 16:51:30','2015-05-16 11:21:30',0),(2,'Australia','2015-05-16 17:10:33','2015-05-16 11:40:33',0);

INSERT INTO `candidate` VALUES (1,1,'Jon','Snow','jon-snow@got.com',0);
```

**Issue** : But `mysqldump` should have put `false` in place of `is_deleted`, don't you think? Also note that when I manually replace `0` by `false` in `mysqldump` for `is_deleted`, I don't fall into Issue 2.

**Issue 2** :

I use flask restless API layer to do CRUD operations.

```
# ... snip ...
manager = flask.ext.restless.APIManager(app, session=mysession)
manager.create_api(Country, methods=['GET'])
manager.create_api(Candidate, methods=['GET','POST'])
# ... snip ...
```

**Issue** : When I hit `/candidate` api, I get below error. It was working fine with `flask-sqlalchemy`

```
ValueError: int_to_boolean only accepts None, 0 or 1
```

*Traceback for Issue 2*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 110, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 270, in error_router
return original_handler(e)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 110, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 110, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 270, in error_router
return original_handler(e)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 110, in wrapped_function
return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/views.py", line 157, in decorator
return func(*args, **kw)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mimerender.py", line 229, in wrapper
result = target(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 149, in dispatch_request
return meth(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/views.py", line 189, in wrapped
return func(*args, **kw)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/views.py", line 1239, in get
return self._search()
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/views.py", line 1194, in _search
result = self._paginated(result, deep)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restless/views.py", line 981, in _paginated
for x in instances[start:end]]
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2228, in __getitem__
return list(res)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 73, in instances
rows = [process[0](row, None) for row in fetch]
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 455, in _instance
populate_state(state, dict_, row, isnew, only_load_props)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 305, in populate_state
populator(state, dict_, row)
File "/home/hussain/workspace/api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 169, in fetch_col
dict_[key] = row[col]
ValueError: int_to_boolean only accepts None, 0 or 1
```

How do I tackle this issue? Please help me out.

Comment: Changed Boolean to TINYINT as of now due to brevity of time.